# как мне ускорить программу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
sub_count = 1
count = 0

for i in range(m):
   i = 10 ** len(str(n))
   if sub_count % i == n:
       count += 1
   sub_count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: А что эта программа в принципе должна делать?

Comment: находить сколько чисел, оканчивающихся на значение n находится в промежутке m, при условии что n и m > 0

Comment: Что такое «промежуток m»? Обычно под «промежутком» понимается что-то протяжённое, а не одно число

Comment: все натуральные числа от 1 до m

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а и правда, странное оформление кода запутывает

Comment: Впрочем, вопрос всё равно есть — до m включительно или нет? От этого зависит, верно или нет. Ну и касательно «ускорить» всё равно — такие задачи решаются не тупым перебором, а размышлениями и поиском каких-нибудь закономерностей, которые позволят оценить количество элементов не прибегая к перебору

Comment: Очевидно, что решения этой задачи перебор вообще не нужен. Задача решается парой формул, а то и одной.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно сосчитать сколько раз повторится остаток *n* в диапазоне чисел *[1, m]*. Обозначим это количество как *f<sub>n,m</sub>*.

Первое наблюдение: *f<sub>n,m</sub> = f<sub>0...0,m-n</sub>*. Вторая запись немного странная: число нулей равно числу знаков в *n*. Если вы сомневаетесь, подумайте как соотносятся *f<sub>n,m</sub>* и *f<sub>n-1,m-1</sub>*.

*f<sub>0...0,m-n</sub>* - это количество чисел кратных *10...0* плюс единица. Что даёт формулу в программе ниже:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
print(1 + (m - n) // 10 ** len(str(n)))
```